# Place vertically centered legend to the right of groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend, groupplots

I want to place the legend to the right of `groupplots` using the `pgfplots` package, and for the legend to be vertically aligned at the center.
In other words, I want the legend to be placed at the point where it says "Put the legend here".

**Question:**
How do I do this?

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=2 by 2,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom,
      y descriptions at=edge left,
    },
    height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small,
    xlabel=time $t$ / h,
    ylabel=$c$ / mol/L,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot% 1
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 2
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 3
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 4
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
  \end{groupplot}
  \node [right=5mm,anchor=west] at
    ($(group c2r1.south east)!0.5!(group c2r2.north east)$) {Put the legend here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add legend to a place to the right of the plots, one needs to add a legend style to the `groupplot` environment where at=() is the key. The (0,0) means the lower left of the corner while (1,1) means the upper right corner. Such system is called `axis description cs` documented on page 103.

```
[legend style={at={(1.03,1.4)}, anchor=north west}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=2 by 2,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom,
      y descriptions at=edge left,
    },
    height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small,
    xlabel=time $t$ / h,
    ylabel=$c$ / mol/L,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot% 1
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 2
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 3
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot[legend style={at={(1.03,1.4)}, anchor=north west}]% 4
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\legend{Put the legend here};
  \end{groupplot}
%  \node [right=5mm,anchor=west] at
%    ($(group c2r1.south east)!0.5!(group c2r2.north east)$) {}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**  The OP has a follow-up and this update adds more info to it. This is the principle for `groupplot`. The `\nextgroupplot[<axis options>]` option are the options that are supplied to the following axes until the next `\nextgroupplot` command is seen by TEX. The order in which figures are typeset in a zigzag order, meaning the right-most figures are the 3rd, 6th and 9th figure. Since the OP wants legends to be vertically center, this solution uses the 9th figure as the reference point and specifies the coordinate`at=(<x,y>)`. The `axis description cs` remains valid. Just be aware that for outer legends `x>1` and `y>1`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=3 by 3,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom,
      y descriptions at=edge left,
    },
    height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,/tikz/font=\small,
    xlabel=time $t$ / h,
    ylabel=$c$ / mol/L,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot% 1
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 2
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 3
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 4
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 5
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 6
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 7
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot% 8
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \nextgroupplot[legend style={at={(1.1,2.2)}, anchor=north west}]% 9   
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \legend{Put the legend here};
  \end{groupplot}
%  \node [right=5mm,anchor=west] at
%    ($(group c2r1.south east)!0.5!(group c2r2.north east)$) {}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works for this case, but due to the magic numbers (1.03,1.4) it suggests to me that it is fragile and depends on the exact dimensions of the plots and the size of the legend box. That is if the height changed or if the legend box had more rows the alignment would be negatively affected. Is there a solution that works independently of the dimensions and the size of the legend box?

Comment: @ILiketoCode -- Please see my update.

Comment: I am slightly dissatisfied with the solution because the `at={(x,y)}` depends on the number of plots and the size of the plots, so some manual tweaking of `(x,y)` is necessary. Nevertheless, I've accepted the answer. Thanks for your attempt!