# Automatically positioning a legend relative to multiple plots in groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, legend, groupplots

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153111/place-vertically-centered-legend-to-the-right-of-groupplots) deals with centered legend placement in a set of plots aligned with `groupplots`. However, as the OP stated in a comment, the (accepted) solution requires some hand tweaking.

I suspect there might be a better way to do this, maybe using the nodes per-plot that `groupplots` is generating as `group cxry`, where `x` is the number of the column and `y` is the number of the row.

However, those nodes don't exist until (I imagine?) `groupplots` has finished plotting (correct me if I'm wrong!). And by that time the legend has already been plotted.

I've thought of a couple of possibilities, but none seem to work:

- Maybe using something like `($(group c1r1)!.5!(group c2r1)$)`?
- Or using the `axis cs` to specify the `y` coordinate, and an intersection like `-| (current page.center)` for the `x`?

Ideally, you could specify a `group legend at={(0.5,1)}` or maybe something like what `positioning` does for a `group legend at=below plot` or something like that.

I understand that, short of that, I will always need some sort of knowledge of the number of plots, so I can decide if it's `group c2r1` or `group c3r1`, but at this point, it's more the centering between those that bothers me.

The MWE below shows this: I can *automatically place a node* where I want the legend, and I can *manually place the legend* relatively close to where that node is. But I want to know if there's a way to *automatically place the legend* there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.groupplots,calc]
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.11,
  horizontal legend/.style={
    every axis legend/.append style={
      at={(0.2,1.18)}, anchor=south east, draw=none, font=\footnotesize,
      draw=none,
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.3cm},
    },
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=4,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        small,
        group style={group size=2 by 1},
      ]
      \nextgroupplot[]
      \addplot[red]  [domain=0:2*pi] {sin(deg(x)};
      \addplot[blue] [domain=0:2*pi] {cos(deg(x)};
      \nextgroupplot[horizontal legend]
      \addplot[red]  [domain=0:pi]   {sin(deg(x)};
      \addlegendentry{sin}
      \addplot[blue] [domain=0:pi]   {cos(deg(x)};
      \addlegendentry{cos}
    \end{groupplot}
    \path ($(group c1r1.north)!.5!(group c2r1.north)$) ++ (0,1) node {HERE};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.groupplots,calc]
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.11,
  horizontal legend/.style={
    every axis legend/.append style={
      at={(0.2,1.18)}, anchor=south east, draw=none, font=\footnotesize,
      draw=none,
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.3cm},
    },
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=4,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        small,
        group style={group size=2 by 1},
      ]
      \nextgroupplot[]
      \addplot[red]  [domain=0:2*pi] {sin(deg(x)};
      \addplot[blue] [domain=0:2*pi] {cos(deg(x)};
      \nextgroupplot[horizontal legend]
      \addplot[red]  [domain=0:pi]   {sin(deg(x)};
      \addlegendentry{sin}
      \addplot[blue] [domain=0:pi]   {cos(deg(x)};
      \addlegendentry{cos}
    \end{groupplot}
    \path ($(group c1r1.north)!.5!(group c2r1.north)$) ++ (0,1) node {HERE};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37568/colors-and-legend-in-groupplots-barplot, where the legend is saved as a reference and placed using a node after the `groupplots` environment is complete.

Comment: Ah, that's the stuff! I couldn't find that before. This question pales in comparison. Should I still leave it up as a sort of redirect? I feel this title is easier to understand. :/

Comment: Do you reckon this is a duplicate? I feel like your question goes further than that, because you're (rightly) asking for a more automated solution that doesn't require manually choosing the right values for `group c2r1`. Maybe you could edit your question to ask about automating that other approach?

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I see the difference. I'll try to edit the question when I have some time.

Comment: once I compile this in my texstudio.. I got the error message something that " Choice '1.11' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/empty l
ine'. I am going to ignore this key."...how we will rectify this..@jja @

Comment: For the record: I added a feature-request to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/55/).